# How to hide a component like ng-hide in emberjs 2.1?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

AngularJS has a `ng-show` and `ng-hide` system to show/hide elements in the DOM. What is the best way to achieve something similar in Ember 2.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ember components have an [`isVisible`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#property_isVisible) flag that you can use which is the easiest way.

You can of course also use css/jQuery or have your own flag that renders or doesn't render the component's content.

Comment: isVisible is deprecated. you may use hidded attribute or classNameBindings.
https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0324-deprecate-component-isvisible.md